# Cannot call value of non-function type 'MPMusicPlayerController'

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm following an XCODE tutorial, and one of the line in his video is

```
var MusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
```

He happens to face no error but, when I put this in my code:

```
var MusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer()
```

I face the error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'MPMusicPlayerController'". I can't figure out what this means nor what mistake I am making.
Would love to understand and learn more.

Answer (score 1):

`MPMusicPlayerController` is part of `MusicKit` framework.

Please, verify if you import `MusicKit` at the top of your file.
If so, please give more details.

Comment: I imported `MediaPlayer` should I be using `MusicKit` instead?

Comment: I just tried adding `MusicKit` and it says "No such module 'MusicKit'"